# How can i unmount All the State Values in react ? is this possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-lifecycle, react-component-unmount

```
this.state = {
  loading: false,
  timer: false,
  showZero: false,
  pin: '',
  error: {
    emptyPin: false,
    checkPin: false,
    wrongPin: false,
    message: '',
    devices: undefined,
    type: 999,
    checkBoxStr: '',
  },
  showDialog: false,
  showSnackBar: false,
  singleButtonDialog: false,
  disabledButton: true,
  checkBox: false,
  seconds: 0,
};
```

this is the State Values , i need to unmount the Values using `Componentwillunmount` if this possible Please let me know

i got this error

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
in VerifyOtp (created by WithStyles(VerifyOtp))
in WithStyles(VerifyOtp) (created by Context.Consumer)
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). When a component unmounts it's state will be gone. If it gets mounted again it will have a new state object. What is the actual problem you are having?

Comment: Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in VerifyOtp (created by WithStyles(VerifyOtp))
    in WithStyles(VerifyOtp) (created by Context.Consumer)

i got this error

Comment: What do you mean by "unmount the values"? Do you just want to reset them to their initial state?

Comment: How can i reset the initial state

Comment: Just have an object with initial state, and then set your state with that.

Comment: please share the code snippets

Comment: Something you are not showing us is causing the error. Put that error message into a web seaarch and you will find lots of results